# Passing an ObservableList javaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

this is my Controller Class, this Class contains methods for add,edit, and remove a task from an ArrayList and a getter for the ObservableList.

```
    public class taskController {
       @FXML  private Button addButton;       
       @FXML  private DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
       @FXML  private TextField descriptionTextField = new TextField();
              private List<task> taskList= new ArrayList<task>();

    public void initialize() {
         datePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());

    public taskController() {
    }

    public void showAddTask() throws IOException {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        AnchorPane taskLayout;
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(taskController.class.getResource("addTask.fxml"));
        taskLayout = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(taskLayout);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

   @FXML private void addTask() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    this.taskList.add(new task(descriptionTextField.getText(),datePicker.getValue().getYear(),datePicker.getValue().getMonthValue(),datePicker.getValue().getDayOfMonth()));
    }

public ObservableList<task> getTaskListView() {
    return FXCollections.observableArrayList(this.taskList);
}
```

When I get the ObservableList from the Main class i get this error.

```
`Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at view.taskController.getTaskListView(taskController.java:93)
at Main.showTask(Main.java:49)
at Main.updateButton(Main.java:61)`
```

This is my Main class:

```
    public class Main extends Application {
          private taskController taskController = new taskController();       
          private feedController feedController = new feedController();
          private Stage primaryStage;
    @FXML private StackPane taskStackPane = new StackPane();
    @FXML private StackPane newsStackPane = new StackPane();
    @FXML private ListView<task> taskListView;
    @FXML private ListView<Calls> callList;

    public void initialize() {
        this.primaryStage = new Stage();
        showNews();
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        VBox mainLayout;
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("App POO");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("assistant.fxml"));
        mainLayout = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();    
    }

          private void showNews() {
              newsStackPane.getChildren().add(feedController.generateObservableNews());         
          }
     private void showTask() {
         taskListView = new ListView<>();
         taskListView.setItems(this.taskController.getTaskListView());   
         taskStackPane.getChildren().add(taskListView);

     }

     public void newTaskButton() throws IOException {
            this.taskController.showAddTask();

        }
```

I dont understand where the problem is, the objects are well instantiated (think so), but the taskList is lossing.

Comment: You did not set the controller instance (i.e. `taskController`) into the `FXMLLoader`. All the adding are done in the instance defined by your FXML file by `fx:id` attribute. You need to either set the controller instance into `FXMLLoader` or get (and keep) the instance from the `FXMLLoader`.

Comment: The stacktrace you posted cannot happen with the provided `getTaskListView` code: `at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at view.taskController.getTaskListView(taskController.java:93)` shows that `ArrayList.get` must occur in the body of the method, not in some method invoked from the body of the method. There is no call to `get` in this method. Are you sure the class was properly build after the last modifications to your code?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly. Additionally, please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: @Jai FXMLLoader set the Location of fxml file in showAddTask() function in taskController class and fx:id is set in fxml file, I tried setting it Global but nothing happen.

Comment: @fabian yeah i have an System.out.println() in getTaskListView() trying to get the first element of the list

Comment: Why hide it in the question? Until you use `addTask` there won't be a first element in `taskList`...

Comment: Because i am testing and forget to write it .. yeah the list is added to the main app with a button who action showTask() in main class